# Why does a Node pointer in a Node class not need template arguments (e.g. in linked lists)?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, linked-list

In the `Node` struct I don't know why I'm supposed to use `Node * forward` as opposed to `Node<T> * forward`. The same question applies to `Node * backward`. At first, I thought it was because forward/backward never needed to "peek" inside their nodes...they're just straight node pointers and they don't care what's there. But then, I found myself reaching into nodes with calls like `T temp = last->backward->data`, and it worked just fine. So my one theory is out the window.

```
template <typename T>
struct Node {
public:
    T data;
    Node<T> * forward { nullptr };  //<-This works...but
    Node * backward { nullptr };    //<-I've been told no <T> is right
};

template <typename T>
class DoublyLinkedList{
public:
    /*
     ...methods...
     */
private:
    unsigned int size {0};
    Node<T> * first {nullptr};
    Node<T> * last {nullptr};
};
```

Any comments or suggestions on how I can better understand this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I think it is a duplicate if you do. The other post, it is essentially saying that (in my case) <T> is implied within struct?

Comment: You don't have to agree with me :) Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Rakete1111 In this case I will! Thanks!